# Cannot Consume ASP.NET REST API Deployed Locally

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rest, http

I have made a very simple Web API in ASP.NET and deployed it locally with IIS, but I cannot seem to use it. I've tried using it with HTTPClient in Xamarin, as well as in Java, but something in the ASP.NET project is not allowing me to access it. I am not sure if the problem is because it's deployed locally, though. Here are the errors I receive in Java and .NET:

Java:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
```

.NET:

```
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>d__64.MoveNext () [0x00478] in <996a681f30a44cd685a4da54e11956e2>:0
```

Calling Method:

```
public async Task<List<School>> GetSchools()
    {
        try
        { 
            var response = await client.GetAsync("schools");
            string responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            List<School> schools = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<School>>(responseJson);
            return schools;
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, if it’s not too much trouble, can you provide us with the code in the controller that you’re trying to call, as well as the client code that you’re using to call the service?

Comment: @BrianDriscoll Hey, thanks for the reply. Here's the code for the controller (which works perfectly and responds with JSON in the tab IIS opens) `[HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<School> GetSchools()
        {
            return _context.Schools;
        }`

Comment: And the calling method is `public async Task<List<School>> GetSchools()
        {
            try
            { 
                var response = await client.GetAsync("schools");
                string responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                List<School> schools = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<School>>(responseJson);
                return schools;
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException e)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }`

Comment: I'm pretty confident that the issue is not in the code, but something in the ASP.NET project is blocking it. I'm not sure if that could be a firewall with making GET requests while deployed locally.

Comment: If you get the response in you web browser in the JSON format at the moment, then there is nothing to do with API you have created. But check the firewall settings and IIS configuration setting for your API.

Comment: It will be better if you add your code to your question. Anyway, nothing in ASP.Net will block your requests if you not actually told him to do so. What base url do you use to invoke your web request? Is it http**S**? For me? It looks like a certificate issue.

Comment: I went into Postman and when I try the url with the "SSL Certificate Verifcation" Setting turned on, there is no response, but when I turn it off, I get the proper response. How can I avoid this SSL Certificate Verification?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by the program using an SSL Certificate. To fix, I just went into the projects properties and unchecked the setting 'Enable SSL'.